Is there a more optimized way to query with chained filters like: (a and b) or (c and d) or (e and f)
I have a table called cache.Geolocation, that has the amount of vehicles per city, given a VersionId and Year. It contains about 12 million rows. The format is as follows:

Now, I need to query it for a given set of vehicles (each vehicle is identified by a versionId and a year).
The query is something like this:
select VersionId, Year, CityId, Count from cache.Geolocation where 
    (VersionId = 175 and Year in (1999,2000)) or 
    (VersionId = 176 and Year in (1996,1997,1998,1999,2000)) or 
    (VersionId = 177 and Year in (1998)) or 
    (VersionId = 178 and Year in (1995,1996)) or 
    (VersionId = 180 and Year in (1997,1998,1999)) or ....

And I have the following index:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Geolocation_Version_Year] ON [cache].[Geolocation]
(
    [VersionId] ASC,
    [Year] ASC
)
INCLUDE([CityId],[Count])

This takes almost 30 seconds to run. Is there a better query, or a better index, or a better way to organize this data, to be able to query faster?

Create a virtual table of version and year columns and join your main table on it? Something like select * from yourtable t inner join (values(996,1999),(996,2000)) v (version,year) on v.version = t.version and v.year = t.year

Please show your execution plan using Paste The Plan

As siggemannen mentions, you might find using a dataset to JOIN to is better.
You can do this with literals and a VALUES clause if this is more of a one of process, doesn't need parameterization, and isn't a huge list:
SELECT VersionId,
       Year, --What year? Use a descriptive (and non keyword) name
       CityId,
       Count --Count of what? Use a descriptive (and non keyword) name
FROM cache.Geolocation GL
     JOIN (VALUES(175,1999),
                 (175,2000),
                 (176,1996),
                 (176,1997),
                 (176,1998),
                 ...
                 (180,1999))V(VersionId, YearCreated) ON GL.VersionId = V.VersionId
                                                    AND GL.Year = V.YearCreated; ; --Guessed Descriptive name for Year

If this is something you're going to do more regularly, with a parametrised query, or a large list, a table variable/type might be better suited. You can index the table, making the JOIN easier for the data engine as well; I assume that the combination of VersionId and Year is unique here. With a table variable, this looks like:
DECLARE @VersionYears table (VersionId int,
                             YearCreated smallint, --Guessed Descriptive name
                             PRIMARY KEY (VersionId, YearCreated));

INSERT INTO @VersionYears (VersionId,
                           Year) Guessed Descrptive name
VALUES(175,1999),
      (175,2000),
      (176,1996),
      (176,1997),
      (176,1998),
      ...
      (180,1999);

SELECT VersionId,
       Year, --What year? Use a descriptive (and non keyword) name
       CityId,
       Count --Count of what? Use a descriptive (and non keyword) name
FROM cache.Geolocation GL
     JOIN @VersionYears VY ON GL.VersionId = VY.VersionId
                          AND GL.Year = VT.YearCreated;


You might have luck if you first filter using the broad criteria, when apply the detailed criteria:
with cte as (
  select VersionId, Year, CityId, Count
  from cache.Geolocation
  where VersionId in (175, 176, 177, 178, 180)
  and Year in (1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000)
)
select *
from cte
where
    (VersionId = 175 and Year in (1999,2000)) or 
    (VersionId = 176 and Year in (1996,1997,1998,1999,2000)) or 
    (VersionId = 177 and Year in (1998)) or 
    (VersionId = 178 and Year in (1995,1996)) or 
    (VersionId = 180 and Year in (1997,1998,1999))

And put an index on (versionId, year).
